# Load named unexported symbols with dlsym?

Tags: dlsym

Is it possible to load a named unexported symbol from a framework using `dlsym`?

The symbol I'm trying to import has a name by which it is referred to within the framework. It is a function I need to call.

I'm trying to do it the usual `dlopen` + `dlsym` way, but when I try to load a symbol that isn't exported, `dlsym` returns a **NULL** pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dlsym` can only load functions that are listed in the symbol table. You can list the symbol table by running `nm` on the framework in question.

You can verify this in the dyld source:
[`ImageLoaderMachOClassic::findExportedSymbol`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-195.5/src/ImageLoaderMachOClassic.cpp) is the internal implementation of dlsym, it simply binary searches the symbol table:

And [`ImageLoaderMachO::parseLoadCmds`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-195.5/src/ImageLoaderMachO.cpp) loads the symbol table from the load commands in the Mach header:

Comment: I have a case where `dsymutil -s` shows me the symbol but `dlsym` does not find it. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849208/how-can-i-get-the-nsautoreleasenopool-address). How could you find such symbols?